# Calculate Sales By Sales Person

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

I have a table with below format.

***Sample table and data***

```
declare @sales table 
(productid int, TransDate date,SalesPerson varchar(100),Amount bigint)

insert into @sales
values
(1 ,         20150101,      50  ,         'S1'),
(1 ,         20150201,      50  ,         'S1'),
(1 ,         20150301,      50  ,         'S1'),
(1 ,         20150401,      50  ,         'S1'),
(1 ,         20150501,      50  ,         'S1'),
(1 ,         20150601,      50  ,         'S2'),
(1 ,         20150701,      50  ,         'S2'),
```

Now, I need to calculate the total sales of each rep and the related sales(sales performed by all sales persons other than than the main sales person)

For example, 
For Sales Person S1, his sales are 250 and related agents(S2) sales(who also involved in the sales serviced by S1 for products 1) will be 100.

The output should be:

```
SalesPerson  Date         MySalesAmount  RelatedSalesPersonSalesAmount
S1           20150101     50             0
S1           20150201     50             0
S1           20150301     50             0
S1           20150401     50             0
S1           20150501     50             0
S1           20150601     0              50
S1           20150701     0              50
S2           20150101     0              50
S2           20150201     0              50
S2           20150301     0              50
S2           20150401     0              50
S2           20150501     0              50
S2           20150601     50             0
S2           20150701     50             0
```

Can anyone help on this to achieve above output with a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following query:

```
declare @sales table 
(productid int, TransDate date,SalesPerson varchar(100),Amount bigint);

insert into @sales(productid, TransDate, Amount, SalesPerson)
values
(1, '20150101', 50, 'S1'),
(1, '20150201', 50, 'S1'),
(1, '20150301', 50, 'S1'),
(1, '20150401', 50, 'S1'),
(1, '20150501', 50, 'S1'),
(1, '20150601', 50, 'S2'),
(1, '20150701', 50, 'S2'),
(1, '20150601', 10, 'S3'),
(1, '20150701', 10, 'S3');

select distinct
  SalesPerson,
  sum(Amount) over (partition by productid, SalesPerson) as MySalesAmount,
  sum(Amount) over (partition by productid) -
    sum(Amount) over (partition by productid, SalesPerson) as RelatedSalesPersonSalesAmount
from @sales;
```

**Output:**

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| SalesPerson | MySalesAmount | RelatedSalesPersonSalesAmount |
+-------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| S1          |           250 |                           120 |
| S2          |           100 |                           270 |
| S3          |            20 |                           350 |
+-------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
```

Test it online with [rextester](https://rextester.com/NNV5686).

**Update:**

```
select
  x.productid,
  x.SalesPerson,
  y.TransDate as [Date],
  iif(x.SalesPerson = y.SalesPerson, y.Amount, 0) as MySalesAmount,
  iif(x.SalesPerson = y.SalesPerson, 0, y.Amount) as RelatedSalesPersonSalesAmount
from (select distinct productid, SalesPerson from @sales) as x
join @sales as y
  on x.productid = y.productid
order by x.productid, x.SalesPerson;
```

**Output:**

```
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| productid | SalesPerson |        Date         | MySalesAmount | RelatedSalesPersonSalesAmount |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
|         1 | S1          | 01.01.2015 00:00:00 |            50 |                             0 |
|         1 | S1          | 01.02.2015 00:00:00 |            50 |                             0 |
|         1 | S1          | 01.03.2015 00:00:00 |            50 |                             0 |
|         1 | S1          | 01.04.2015 00:00:00 |            50 |                             0 |
|         1 | S1          | 01.05.2015 00:00:00 |            50 |                             0 |
|         1 | S1          | 01.06.2015 00:00:00 |             0 |                            50 |
|         1 | S1          | 01.07.2015 00:00:00 |             0 |                            50 |
|         1 | S2          | 01.01.2015 00:00:00 |             0 |                            50 |
|         1 | S2          | 01.02.2015 00:00:00 |             0 |                            50 |
|         1 | S2          | 01.03.2015 00:00:00 |             0 |                            50 |
|         1 | S2          | 01.04.2015 00:00:00 |             0 |                            50 |
|         1 | S2          | 01.05.2015 00:00:00 |             0 |                            50 |
|         1 | S2          | 01.06.2015 00:00:00 |            50 |                             0 |
|         1 | S2          | 01.07.2015 00:00:00 |            50 |                             0 |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to add the DateKey column to the output?

Comment: @bipro, I do not see the `DataKey` column in the declaration of the `@sales` table.

Comment: I have just edited my question. Please refer the updated format I am looking for

Comment: @bipro, why did you choose `20150201`?

Comment: The updated query output is not matching the output I am looking for. Can you please verify once.

Answer (score 1):

This seems complicated.  Obviously, the sales person's amount is easy enough:

```
select salesperson, sum(salesamt)
from t
group by salesperson;
```

For the related amount, we need sales amounts for other sales people who have sold the same products.

I think a self join comes to the rescue:

```
select t.salesperson, 
       sum(case when t.salesperson = t2.salesperson then t.salesamnt end) as mysales,
       sum(case when t.salesperson <> t2.salesperson then t.salesamnt end) as othersales
from t join
     t t2
     on t.product = t2.product
group by t.salesperson
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
declare @sales table 
(productid int, transDate date, amount bigint, salesperson varchar(100))

insert into @sales
values
(1 ,         '20150101',      50  ,         'S1'),
(1 ,         '20150201',      50  ,         'S1'),
(1 ,         '20150301',      50  ,         'S1'),
(1 ,         '20150401',      50  ,         'S1'),
(1 ,         '20150501',      50  ,         'S1'),
(1 ,         '20150601',      50  ,         'S2'),
(1 ,         '20150701',      50  ,         'S2')

;with cteSales as
(select s.salesperson, productid, sum(amount) amount
from @sales s
group by s.salesperson, productid)
select s1.salesperson, s1.productid, 
       sum(case when s1.salesperson = s2.salesperson  then s1.amount else 0 end) as mysales,
       sum(case when s1.salesperson <> s2.salesperson   then s2.amount else 0 end) as othersales
 from cteSales s1 inner join cteSales s2
on s1.productid = s2.productid
group by s1.salesperson, s1.productid
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I have edited my question with a slight change in requirement. Is it possible to get the output like in the edited version?

Comment: @bipro - you can try above solution based on your previous requirement but seems your requirement updated again.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @sales table 
(productid int, SalesAmt int , SalesPerson varchar(100))

insert into @sales
values
(1 ,         50  ,         'S1'),
(2  ,        50   ,        'S2'),
(1  ,        100 ,         'S2'),
(3,         100 ,         'S1'),
(3 ,         150 ,         'S3'),
(2 ,         100  ,        'S3')


select t.salesperson, sum(SalesAmt) [Person Sale],
   (select sum(SalesAmt) from  @sales s where s.SalesPerson <> t.salesperson 
) [Total Sale]
from @sales t 
group by t.salesperson
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg95D.png)